# flutter Navigator.push doesn't work and show me this error NoSuchMethodError: The method 'ancestorStateOfType' was called on null

Tags: flutter

I have a list of items and i want when the user click on an item, appear another window, i write the code as shown bellow

```
return ListTile( leading: Container(
 padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0 , top: 8.0 ,bottom: 8.0),
 child: Column(
   children: <Widget>[
     _buildGymLocationRow(gym), // method 
      SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
     _builDescrRateRow(gym), ], ), )

,onTap: (){ Navigator.push( context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new gymDetails()));
},
);
```

but when i click on the item or ListTile, it's show me this error.. i don't know what i have to do.. please I need help

> I/flutter ( 9134): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'ancestorStateOfType' was called on null.

Comment: can you upload some more data (error). It looks like insufficient data has been provided.

Comment: Widget _buildRow(gymInfo gym) {
  BuildContext context;

  return ListTile(
   leading: Container(
     padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0 , top: 8.0 ,bottom: 8.0),
     child: Column(
       children: <Widget>[
         _buildGymLocationRow(gym),
          SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
          _builDescrRateRow(gym),   ],),  ),
onTap: (){
  Navigator.push(
      context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new gymDetails()));
}, );}

Comment: You declared `BuildContext context` but it doesn't have any value.

Comment: Thanks for your help ,I solved the problem

Comment: how did you solve your problem? Kindly explain.

Comment: @VipiNNegi I saved the BuildContext as object and pass it as parameter in the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `NoSuchMethodError: The method 'ancestorStateOfType' was called on null.` thrown is most likely caused by the widget having been removed from the tree. It's possible that it doesn't have a context anymore. To solve this issue, you may want to consider keeping track of the `BuildContext context` that you're using by storing it as a variable or passing it as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, that why, thanks